# I want the city selected in the first combo box not to appear in the second

Tags: java, swing, actionlistener, jcombobox, selecteditem

If I choose a city FROM: `JComboBox` then it shouldn't appear in TO: combo box. How can I code the `ActionListener` of this action listener?

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SgZhb.png)

### Code:

```
public class CityFromTo {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        
        String[] cFrom = {"Choose", "Istanbul", "New York", "London", "Milano", "Tokyo", "Paris", "Moscow", "Elâzığ"};
        String[] cTo = {"Choose", "Istanbul", "New York", "London", "Milano", "Tokyo", "Paris", "Moscow", "Elâzığ"};
        
        JLabel from = new JLabel("FROM : ");
        JLabel to = new JLabel("   TO : ");

        JComboBox comboFrom = new JComboBox(cFrom);
        JComboBox comboTo = new JComboBox(cTo);
        
        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        frame.setLayout(new FlowLayout());

        frame.add(from);
        frame.add(comboFrom);
        frame.add(to);
        frame.add(comboTo);
        
        frame.setSize(400, 350);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

Comment: Would it be possible to disable that city rather than removing it? From a user interface standpoint, it would be better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I reworked your code to get away from static.  You only need one list of cities for your from and to `JComboBoxes`.

You use an `ActionListener` to listen for changes in the from `JComboBox`, and remove the city from the to `JComboBox`.  We remove the city by removing all the cities and adding them back, one at a time.  This allows the user to change his mind about the from city.

Here's the complete runnable code.

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.FlowLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

import javax.swing.BorderFactory;
import javax.swing.JComboBox;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;

public class CityFromTo implements Runnable {
    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
       SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new CityFromTo());
    }
    
    private JComboBox<String> comboFrom;
    private JComboBox<String> comboTo;
    
    private String[] cities = {"Choose", "Istanbul", "New York", "London", 
            "Milano", "Tokyo", "Paris", "Moscow", "Elâzığ"};

    @Override
    public void run() {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        
        frame.add(createMainPanel(), BorderLayout.CENTER);
        
        frame.pack();
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }
    
    private JPanel createMainPanel() {
        JPanel panel = new JPanel(new FlowLayout());
        panel.setBorder(BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(5, 5, 5, 5));
        panel.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(400, 350));
        
        JLabel from = new JLabel("FROM : ");
        panel.add(from);
        
        comboFrom = new JComboBox<>(cities);
        comboFrom.addActionListener(new FromListener());
        panel.add(comboFrom);
        
        JLabel to = new JLabel("   TO : ");
        panel.add(to);
        
        comboTo = new JComboBox<>(cities);
        panel.add(comboTo);
        
        return panel;
    }
    
    public class FromListener implements ActionListener {

        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) {
            String city = (String) comboFrom.getSelectedItem();
            comboTo.removeAllItems();
            for (String s : cities) {
                if (!s.equals(city)) {
                    comboTo.addItem(s);
                }
            }
        }
        
    }

}
```

Comment: Thank you soooo much... Greetings from Istanbul :)