# How can I add live time to a JPanel and when button pressed time to other JPanel?

Tags: java, swing, jpanel, jlabel

The aim of code is that the Tıme and milliseconds wıll run always. When the button pressed the current time at that moment will appear on the greenPanel. I made a screenshot.

My app must look like this:

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/9E56K.png]

Any help?

My button is not sending the time to greenPanel.

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Date;

import javax.swing.*;

public class TimePanel {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        
        Font timeFont = new Font("Helvetica", Font.BOLD, 50);
        Font msFont = new Font("Helvetica", Font.PLAIN, 72);
        
        Date dateNow = new Date(); // current date and time
        
        SimpleDateFormat timeFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm:ss"); // current time
        SimpleDateFormat msFormat = new SimpleDateFormat(".S"); // milliseconds
        SimpleDateFormat sendToGreenFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm:ss.S");
        
        String timeString = timeFormat.format(dateNow);
        String msString = msFormat.format(dateNow);
        
        JLabel timeLabel = new JLabel(timeString, JLabel.CENTER);
        timeLabel.setFont(timeFont);
        timeLabel.setForeground(new Color(242, 242, 242));
        timeLabel.setBounds(0, 25, 240, 50);
        
        JLabel msLabel = new JLabel(msString, JLabel.CENTER);
        msLabel.setFont(msFont);
        msLabel.setForeground(new Color(242, 242, 242));
        msLabel.setBounds(0, 25, 240, 65);
        
        JButton sendButton = new JButton("Send to Green");
        sendButton.setBounds(585, 260, 150, 25);
        
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Time Panel");
        frame.setLayout(null);
        
        JPanel greenPanel = new JPanel();
        greenPanel.setLayout(new GridLayout(10,1));
        greenPanel.setBackground(new Color(18, 64, 55, 255));
        greenPanel.setBounds(20, 20, 500, 500);
        
        JPanel timePanel = new JPanel();
        timePanel.setLayout(null);
        timePanel.setBackground(new Color(89, 21, 33, 255));
        timePanel.setBounds(540, 20, 240, 100);
        
        JPanel msPanel = new JPanel(); // milliseconds panel.
        msPanel.setLayout(null);
        msPanel.setBackground(new Color(38, 7, 15, 255));
        msPanel.setBounds(540, 140, 240, 100);
        
        sendButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                
                String timeToGreenString = sendToGreenFormat.format(dateNow);
                
                JLabel timeToGreenLabel = new JLabel(timeToGreenString);
                timeToGreenLabel.setFont(timeFont);
                timeToGreenLabel.setForeground(new Color(242, 242, 242));
                timeToGreenLabel.setBounds(0, 25, 240, 50);
                
                greenPanel.add(timeToGreenLabel);
            }
        });
                
        timePanel.add(timeLabel);
        msPanel.add(msLabel);
        
        frame.add(greenPanel);
        frame.add(timePanel);
        frame.add(msPanel);
        frame.add(sendButton);
        
        frame.setSize(800, 600);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        frame.setVisible(true);

    }

}
```

Comment: Call `greenPanel.revalidate()` and `greenPanel.repaint()` after `greenPanel.add` as place to start

Comment: Why should anyone help you after you ignored the Swing principles outlined in the [answer to your previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66203198/i-want-the-city-selected-in-the-first-combobox-not-to-appear-in-the-second-combo/66204809#66204809)?

Comment: 1) Use a [`CardLayout`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/CardLayout.html) as shown in [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5786005/418556). 2) Java GUIs have to work on different OS', screen size, screen resolution etc.  using different PLAFs in different locales.  As such, they are not conducive to pixel perfect layout.  Instead use layout managers, or [combinations of them](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5630271/418556) along with layout padding and borders for [white space](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17874718/418556).

Comment: Gilbert Le Blanc Did I do something wrong? Your code (in my previous question) was great. Why did you say that to me? I answerd your answer with Thenk you. Didn't you see it? Also I am trying to understand Java code architecture.

Comment: 1) Tip: Add @GilbertLeBlanc (or whoever, the `@` is important) to *notify* the person of a new comment. 2) The answer linked by Gilbert demonstrated how to use layouts. Your next question failed to incorporate that advice.

Comment: @AndrewThompson I didn't understand why i failed because already I don't know Swing principles. But I will learn. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a GUI I came up with.

[image: Time Panel GUI]

When I create a Swing GUI, or most any other Java application, I use the [model / view / controller](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model%E2%80%93view%E2%80%93controller) pattern.  In short, this pattern using Swing means:

1. The view (Swing components) will read from the model.
2. The view will not change anything in the model.
3. The controller will update the model and update the view.

I create an application model using one or more plain Java getter / setter classes. I create a view by using Swing components and [Swing layout managers](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/visual.html).  Finally, I create one or more controllers by using [Swing listeners](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/intro.html).  Controllers are where you seem to have the most difficulty understanding.

Here are the most important points I want you to take away from the code I will post.

1. Always start a Swing application with a call to the `SwingUtilities` `invokeLater` method.  This method ensures that your Swing components will be created and executed on the [Event Dispatch Thread](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/dispatch.html).
2. Get out of static code and group your code into Java methods.  You can see in my code that the only static method is the `main` method which starts the application.  My main method has one line of code.  The rest of the application uses methods and classes.
3. Do not use absolute positioning (`setBounds`).  Use [Swing layout managers](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/index.html).  You can see examples of Swing layout managers throughout my code.
4. Create multiple JPanels for one JFrame.  Create each main JPanel in a separate method.  This allows you to combine Swing layout managers in an application.
5. In this particular application, the controllers were so simple that I made them anonymous classes.  I created two anonymous classes, one to update the time panel on the left, and one to run the two clocks in the control panel.  Controllers should always be separate classes from your model and your view.

The next time you post a question, I don't want to see all your code in the main method.  I don't want to see absolute positioning.  I want you to take the time to learn the concepts I've outlined in this answer, or you will never be able to create complex Swing applications.  Finally, you should go through Oracle's complete [Swing tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/index.html).  You can skip the Netbeans section.

Here's the code.  I didn't bother centering the times in the time panel on the left.

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.FlowLayout;
import java.awt.Font;
import java.awt.GridBagConstraints;
import java.awt.GridBagLayout;
import java.awt.Insets;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.time.LocalDateTime;
import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter;

import javax.swing.BorderFactory;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.JTextArea;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;
import javax.swing.Timer;

public class TimePanel implements Runnable {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new TimePanel());
    }
    
    private JLabel timeLabel;
    private JLabel msLabel;
    
    private JTextArea textArea;
    
    private TimeModel model;
    
    public TimePanel() {
        this.model = new TimeModel();
    }
    
    @Override
    public void run() {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Time Panel");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        
        frame.add(createTextPanel(), BorderLayout.CENTER);
        frame.add(createControlPanel(), BorderLayout.AFTER_LINE_ENDS);
        
        frame.pack();
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        frame.setVisible(true);
        
        Timer timer = new Timer(50, new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) {
                updateControlPanel();
            }
        });
        timer.start();
    }   
    
    private JPanel createTextPanel() {
        JPanel panel = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
        panel.setBorder(BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(5, 5, 5, 5));
        
        JPanel innerPanel = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
        innerPanel.setBackground(model.getBackgroundTextColor());
        innerPanel.setBorder(BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(10, 10, 10, 10));
        
        textArea = new JTextArea(8, 10);
        textArea.setBackground(model.getBackgroundTextColor());
        textArea.setForeground(model.getForegroundColor());
        textArea.setFont(model.getTimeFont());
        innerPanel.add(textArea, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        
        JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane(innerPanel);
        panel.add(scrollPane);
        return panel;
    }   

    private JPanel createControlPanel() {
        JPanel panel = new JPanel(new FlowLayout());
        panel.setBorder(BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(5, 5, 5, 5));
        
        JPanel innerPanel = new JPanel(new GridBagLayout());
        
        GridBagConstraints gbc = new GridBagConstraints();
        gbc.anchor = GridBagConstraints.CENTER;
        gbc.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
        gbc.insets = new Insets(0, 5, 10, 5);
        gbc.gridx = 0;
        gbc.gridy = 0;
        
        JPanel timePanel = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
        timePanel.setBorder(BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(5, 10, 5, 10));
        timePanel.setBackground(model.getBackgroundControlColor());
        
        timeLabel = new JLabel(model.getTime());
        timeLabel.setBackground(model.getBackgroundControlColor());
        timeLabel.setFont(model.getTimeFont());
        timeLabel.setForeground(model.getForegroundColor());
        timePanel.add(timeLabel, BorderLayout.CENTER);

        JPanel msPanel = new JPanel();
        msPanel.setBackground(model.getBackgroundControlColor());
        
        msLabel = new JLabel(model.getMSTime());
        msLabel.setBackground(model.getBackgroundControlColor());
        msLabel.setFont(model.getMSFont());
        msLabel.setForeground(model.getForegroundColor());
        msPanel.add(msLabel);
        
        Dimension t = timePanel.getPreferredSize();
        Dimension m = msPanel.getPreferredSize();
        int width = Math.max(t.width, m.width);
        int height = Math.max(t.height, m.height);
        Dimension a = new Dimension(width, height);
        
        timePanel.setPreferredSize(a);
        msPanel.setPreferredSize(a);
        
        innerPanel.add(timePanel, gbc);
        
        gbc.gridy++;
        innerPanel.add(msPanel, gbc);

        gbc.gridy++;
        JButton sendButton = new JButton("Send to Green");
        sendButton.setFont(model.getButtonFont());
        innerPanel.add(sendButton, gbc);
        
        sendButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) {
                textArea.append(model.getDisplayTime());
                textArea.append(System.lineSeparator());
            }
        });
        
        panel.add(innerPanel);
                    
        return panel;
    }
    
    public void updateControlPanel() {
        timeLabel.setText(model.getTime());
        msLabel.setText(model.getMSTime());
    }
    
    public class TimeModel {
        
        private final Color foregroundColor;
        private final Color backgroundTextColor;
        private final Color backgroundControlColor;
        
        private final DateTimeFormatter timeFormat;
        private final DateTimeFormatter msFormat;
        private final DateTimeFormatter displayFormat;
        
        private final Font timeFont;
        private final Font msFont;
        private final Font buttonFont;
        
        public TimeModel() {
            this.foregroundColor = new Color(242, 242, 242);
            this.backgroundTextColor = new Color(18, 64, 55);
            this.backgroundControlColor = new Color(89, 21, 33);
            
            this.timeFormat = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("HH:mm:ss");
            this.msFormat = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern(".SSS");
            this.displayFormat = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("HH:mm:ss.SSS");
            
            String fontName = "Helvetica";
            this.msFont = new Font(fontName, Font.PLAIN, 72);
            this.timeFont = new Font(fontName, Font.BOLD, 48);
            this.buttonFont = new Font(fontName, Font.PLAIN, 16);   
        }
        
        public String getTime() {
            return timeFormat.format(getCurrentTime());
        }
        
        public String getMSTime() {
            return msFormat.format(getCurrentTime());
        }
        
        public String getDisplayTime() {
            return displayFormat.format(getCurrentTime());
        }
        
        public Color getForegroundColor() {
            return foregroundColor;
        }

        public Color getBackgroundTextColor() {
            return backgroundTextColor;
        }

        public Color getBackgroundControlColor() {
            return backgroundControlColor;
        }

        public Font getTimeFont() {
            return timeFont;
        }

        public Font getMSFont() {
            return msFont;
        }

        public Font getButtonFont() {
            return buttonFont;
        }

        private LocalDateTime getCurrentTime() {
            return LocalDateTime.now();
        }
        
    }

}
```