# How to make a grid that will acomodate my JTable and the rest of my components?

Tags: java, swing, user-interface

I create this JTable that should be next to my other component of my panel, but after setting it's size and its position it only reduce the size of the actual list but not where is contained, ditto for the Label, which doesn't have to be that big.

```
  public void addComponentToPane(Container pane) {
    TabEst est = new TabEst();
    JTabbedPane tabbedPane = new JTabbedPane();
    
JTable tabla = new JTable(data, columnas);
tabla.setSize(100, 200);
tabla.setAutoResizeMode(JTable.AUTO_RESIZE_OFF);
tabla.setDragEnabled(false);
tabla.setBounds(15, 15, 15, 15);
   
    JLabel listado = new JLabel("Listado Oficial");

    listado.setLocation(5, 10);
    JPanel card1 = new JPanel() {
        //Dimensions of the Panel
        @Override
        public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
            Dimension size = super.getPreferredSize();
            size.width += 250;
            return size;
        }
    };
    card1.setLayout(new GridLayout(2, 2));
    card1.setBorder(BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(100, 100, 100, 100));
    card1.add(listado, BorderLayout.NORTH);
    card1.add(new JScrollPane(tabla), BorderLayout.WEST);
    est.addComponentToPane(card1);
```

Here's what it looks like now.

[image]

Here's how I'd like it to look.

[image]

Comment: So, what do you want your GUI to look like?  Can you draw a sketch or make some ASCII art that shows what you do want?

Comment: I'd like it to look like this, somewhat like this...
https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/808229198074085377/821602845702750238/GUI_Sketch.png

Comment: Ok.  By tabs, I'm assuming you mean a JTabbedPane.  Each JLabel goes into a label JPanel using a FlowLayput.    The JTable goes into a JScrollPane which goes into the CENTER of a table JPanel using a BorderLayout.  The JFreeChart goes into a chart JPanel.  One label JPanel, the table JPanel and chart JPanel go into a label-title-chart JPanel with a BoxLayout or a GridBagLayout.  I'd have to experiment.  The other JLabel and the JTabbedPane go into a label-tabbed JPanel, again with either a BoxLayout or a GridBagLayout.  The two final JPanels go into the WEST and EAST of the JFrame BorderLayout

Comment: Here's one of my recent [Stack Overflow answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66219696/how-can-i-add-live-time-to-a-jpanel-and-when-button-pressed-time-to-other-jpanel/66241216#66241216) where I create multiple JPanels to put a GUI together.  Use the model / view / controller pattern and create each JPanel in a separate method or class.